# Getting assosiated ids to checkboxes in for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following code:

```
foreach($redeemSales as $sale) { ?>
     <tr  value='<?php echo $sale['id']; ?>'>
          <td><?php echo $sale["submissionId"];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $sale["ring"];?></td>
          <td><?php echo formatFullDate($sale["soldDate"]) ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $sale["saleType"]; ?></td>
          <td>   
          <div class="col-lg-8">
               <select name="claimTypes[]" class="form-control redeemOptions">
                    <option value="">Choose Gift</option>
                    <option value="CD">Credit (CD)</option>
                    <option value="Amex">American Express Card (Amex)</option>
               </select>
          </div>
      </td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
```

I am getting all `claimTypes` using code:

```
 var cclaim = $('select[name="claimTypes[]"]').serialize();
```

The problem is, I am not sure, since its a for loop, I can't figure out which choosen option is for which `saleId`.

How can I get the associated `saleId` for all selected `claimTypes` other than first option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
....
<select name="claimTypes[]" class="redeemOptions" data-id="<?php echo @sale['id']; ?>">
...

$('select.redeemOptions').filter(function(){ 
   return $(this).val() != "";
 }).each(function() {
   var saleId = $(this).data("id");
   var selectedRedeemValue = $(this).val();
   console.log(saleId + ": " + selectedRedeemValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<select name="claimTypes_<?php echo @sale['id']; ?>" class="form-control redeemOptions">
...
var cclaim = $('select[name^="claimTypes"]').serialize();
```

Although not clear why you would have multiple (same) selects in the same form.

Comment: I need to select multiple saleIds and their corresponding claimTypes, E.g i want to get var saleIds = 1,2,3,4  and claimTypes = abc,def,geh,agf